# Can I format variables like strings in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, function, global-variables

I want to use printing command bellow in many places of my script. But I need to keep replacing "Survived" with some other string.

```
print(df.Survived.value_counts())
```

Can I automate the process by formating variable the same way as string? So if I want to replace "Survived" with "different" can I use something like:

```
var = 'different'
text = 'df.{}.value_counts()'.format(var)
print(text)
```

unfortunately this prints out "df.different.value_counts()" as as a string, while I need to print the value of df.different.value_counts()

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure alot of IDEs, have this option that is called refactoring, and it allows you to change a similar line of code/string on every line of code to what you need it to be.

I'm aware of VSCode's way of refactoring, is by selecting a part of the code and right click to select the option called change all occurances. This will replace the exact code on every line if it exists.

But if you want to do what you proposed, then `eval('df.{}.value_counts()'.format(var))` is an option, but this is very unsecured and dangerous, so a more safer approach would be importing the ast module and using it's literal_eval function which is safer. `ast.literal_eval('df.{}.value_counts()'.format(var))`.

if `ast.literal_eval()` doesn't work then try this final solution that works.

```
def cat():
    return 1

text = locals()['df.{}.value_counts'.format(var)]()
```

Comment: `eval` is evil :)

Comment: it is evil, but that's also the only possible direct answer to his question.

Comment: No, you can still use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: yes that is right, i'll edit my answer to update on that.

Comment: this code: ast.literal_eval('df.{}.value_counts()'.format(var)) gives me an error message:  malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x00000275AB9FCB08> and I did successfully imported ast

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide another solution, and this time this one 100% works.

Comment: if this helped you, upvote it and mark it as a solution!

Comment: I just copy and pasted your code as I on't understand it but I get error message: 'df.different.value_counts()' - and I'm confused why doesn't it like a string?

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-f6b97d9cab89> in <module>
      2     return 1
      3 
----> 4 text = locals()['df.{}.value_counts()'.format(var)]()

KeyError: 'df.different.value_counts()'

Comment: oh my bad, i made a slight typo, it should work now.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-b0f0107decb4> in <module>
      2     return 1
      3 
----> 4 text = locals()['df.{}.value_counts'.format(var)]()

KeyError: 'df.different.value_counts'

Answer (score 0):

Found the way: print(df[var].value_counts())